# Consistency of the risk estimator in the L1 regularized logistic regression

Tags: logistic, mathematical-statistics, lasso, consistency

Prof. Ryan Tibshirani in CMU explained in his class notes how to prove the consistency of the risk estimator in the L1 regularized linear regression, but how to prove the consistency of the risk estimator in the L1 regularized logistic regression?

ClassNotes http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~ryantibs/statml/lectures/sparsity.pdf

Comment: +1 - no idea how to prove such theorem but the lecture notes are gold.